# ScrollRectToVisible not scrolling immediately

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have the following code

```
        if(self.roCount < 4)
        {
            [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 50, 1, 1) animated:NO];    
        }
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

I need the tableview to scroll BEFORE it tries to delete the row. This is because if I get down to the last 4 rows, trying to delete it throws an exception relating to the animation not having enough room to animate due to the header I have in place.

If I change this code to scroll when `self.roCount` is higher so I can see if it even works, it scrolls, but not until AFTER the cell has been deleted. Shouldn't it scroll BEFORE it tries to delete the cell? Why do I not see the scroll happening until after the cell has been deleted?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `scrollRectToVisible:` with `animated` set to `NO`, that executes immediately, but does show up on screen until the next display cycle.

To get the effect you want, you should probably scroll with animation, then after that animation completes, delete the rows.

Comment: Even if I set animated to YES, it still doesn't scroll before the cell is deleted, causing an exception to be thrown if I try to delete one (the first one) of the last 4 cells (and I am currently scrolled all the way to the bottom and the first cell extends beyond the header view, so I only see half of it).

Basically, if I put a breakpoint on the line that deletes the cell, I want the tableview to have already scrolled by then.

Comment: Correct. You must wait until after the animation completes before deleting the rows. A simple way to do that would be to put the delete into a separate selector and use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`

Comment: Would that not lock the main thread while its waiting for the delay?